# Safe way to share a folder with a VMware machine on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware, network-shares

So, I want to share a Windows folder on the host with a VMware virtual machine.
To do this, I need to share this folder on the Windows side. But who do I share it with? The list includes:

- Administrator
- MyUsername
- Homegroup
- Guest
- Everyone

No VMware around. Things work only if I allow one of the last two groups. But who is this "Guest"? Are there any security risks if I share the folder with "him"?

There gotta be a way to share with VM only...

Comment: Who you share it with entirely depends on who you WANT to share it with.  Out of those choices I would assume, you want to share it, with the current Windows profile your logged into.  `Guest` is the default `Guest` account built into Windows.  Are you sure the choice is `Admin` and not `Administrator`?

Comment: @Ramhound indeed, it is Administrator (edited). However the Guest account is _turned off_ on my machine. I want to share the folder only with the OS running on a virtual machine (Ubuntu in my case).

Comment: don't use **guest**

Comment: If your vm has linux you need samba to be installed and then you can mount it.

Comment: @Ramhound why cannot I? I open it to Guest, launch the machine and things work like a charm. All done from one and only admin account of mine on a single machine (Guest is closed on my computer). This should make it all safe to the outside network, right?

Comment: @cybernard I just added a comment to your answer, but your nickname just would not be detected there to notify you...

Comment: @cybernard and _why_ using **guest** might be unsafe?

Comment: its a generic account that has too many permissions, and hackers can abuse it.  It traditionally, has access to a couple internal non-obvious functions that hackers can exploit, thou I don't know which ones.  If you start enabling the **guest** account you **will** accidentally do it on a production, internet facing system, and the whole system will be hacked.  Game Over!!

Comment: A guest account has less permissions the a normal User account...

Comment: @cybernard I guess there could be some security hole, yeah. But as long as I keep guest account disabled. I see no reason not to share anything with it (since it is in the list even if the account is disabled). And I guess it would not be possible to authorize as a guest over the Internet.

Comment: @user3496846 - There are multiple reasons to be able to share a network drive with a Guest account.  One such reason would be that a Guest account still could use access to a shared network drive.  There really isn't that much difference between `Guest` and `MyUsername` from a permission perceptive (some differences though)

Comment: Share the folder the same way you share a folder on a local network and on the virtual machine, map the folder to a drive, it's safe and secure as long as you turn on password protected sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new user, from the control panel and users.  Inside the VM you will be prompted for a username and password, so as long as you enter valid credentials inside the VM it doesn't matter.

If you use **everyone** you will have a share without username or password limited to whatever permissions you assign.

Linux version:
smbmount //servername/sharename /mountdirectory -o rw,username=mywindowsusername,password=mywindowspassword
The mount equivelant is:

mount -t smbfs //servername/sharename /mountdirectory -o rw,username=mywindowsusername,password=mywindowspassword

Comment: Ok. so, I created a passworded user - called it "VMware". Then I shared the folder with it. But at what step am I "prompted for username and password"? Sorry, I don't quite understand.

Comment: Sorry, linux will not prompt you as such, I added the mount commands above.

Comment: Thanks for the edit (cant upvote yet, < 15 rep). I see. So I installed samba and ran the command. Got a complain statement on "smbfs". Used "cifs" instead (provided by cifs-utils). Ran the command again (providing VMware credentials). I can read see the contents of the folder now, but it is Read-only. VMware on the host has read and write permission though. What should I do?

Comment: before the username add **rw,**  so -o rw,username<etc>. (note:there is a comma after the **w**.  You will need to un-mount and mount again as specified.

Comment: also added "uid=1000," right before "rw" now I finally have write permission. thanks!